# need guidance for cybersecurity job

Tags: career, programming

I'm 17 yrs old and I'm Thai. I have been in a military school and I really love computer stuff especially security stuff.
My question here is what should my career be and what could I study now as a fundamental.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general education. 

Comment: Sorry - we aren't in a position to define your career for you. We can answer specific questions here.

Comment: But feel free to hop onto the Sec.SE chat, or contact me on email if you have any questions. It's one of the things about the InfoSec community, tons of awesome people who offer help.

Answer (score 5):

As a *fundamental*, try programming -- in particular low-level stuff like assembly and C, because everything with computer is much clearer when you understand what goes on under the cover. Not that you would actually use a lot of assembly or C afterwards; it is for its enlightening value.

Comment: To add onto this check out overthewire.org, hackthissite.org and smashthestack.org. Also securitytube.net and pauldotcom.com. Look at certifications like Security+ and Certified Ethical Hacker. Basically the name of the game is read, read, read, read, read, read, do, do, do, do, do, do and the learning never ends.

Answer (score 2):

Start with finding out what education tracks you can have in your country (or abroad if you have the financial means). It's important that before you start with security you have a very good fundamental understanding of how computers work. So try to find out what universities offer a program where you can get, for instance, a bachelor degree in computer science and a master degree in information security.

That said there is a lot of stuff you can learn on the side. I would suggest searching this website for similar questions. You could also have a go at webgoat, smash the stack, damn vulnerable linux,... etc. Note that you will need to have some basic understanding on programming, databases, webprogramming and